# How to execute a function with retries on timeout?

Tags: clojure, timeout, future

Suppose I use the following code to ensure my code times out:

```
(defmacro with-timeout [millis & body]
    `(let [future# (future ~@body)]
      (try
        (.get future# ~millis java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit/MILLISECONDS)
        (catch java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException x# 
          (do
            (future-cancel future#)
            nil)))))
```

Now I want to make it retry 3 times (if it times out) after a 5 second interval. Do I do it on the `TimeoutException` - or do I compose it some other way?

My question is:  **How to execute a function with retries on timeout?**

Answer (score 2):

`deref` has a variant that accepts a timeout. Using this we can implement `with-timeout` without Java interop.

```
(defmacro with-timeout [millis & body]
  `(loop [tries# 3]
     (if (pos? tries#)
       (let [future# (future ~@body)
             result# (deref future# ~millis ::timeout)]
         (if (= result# ::timeout)
           (do (future-cancel future#)
               (recur (dec tries#)))
           result#)))))
```

(This is not a 100% 'hygienic' because the `::timeout` sentinel value could theoretically clash with the value returned by the `body` forms.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution using core.async. It is quite naive as it does not deal with error handling. I am also not sure if it is exiting the go call cleanly on timeout.

```
(ns async
  (:require [clojure.core.async :as a]))

(defmacro with-timeout [millis & body]
  `(loop [tries# 0]
     (if (> tries# 3)
       (throw (Exception. "Timed out. (3)"))
       (let [result# (a/alt!!
                       (a/go ~@body)      ([v# ch] v#)
                       (a/timeout ~millis) :async/timed-out)]
         (if (= result# :async/timed-out)
           (recur (inc tries#))
           result#)))))
```